# How can I get the city, state from my xdocument

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have a xdocument (pasted below)

How can I query it to get the city and state out of it?
ex. I might want to query by type where the type value is 'locality'

```
<GeocodeResponse>
  <status>OK</status>
  <result>
    <type>postal_code</type>
    <formatted_address>San Francisco, CA 94102, USA</formatted_address>
    <address_component>
      <long_name>94102</long_name>
      <short_name>94102</short_name>
      <type>postal_code</type>
    </address_component>
    <address_component>
      <long_name>San Francisco</long_name>
      <short_name>SF</short_name>
      <type>locality</type>
      <type>political</type>
    </address_component>
    <address_component>
      <long_name>San Francisco County</long_name>
      <short_name>San Francisco County</short_name>
      <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
      <type>political</type>
    </address_component>
    <address_component>
      <long_name>California</long_name>
      <short_name>CA</short_name>
      <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
      <type>political</type>
    </address_component>
    <address_component>
      <long_name>United States</long_name>
      <short_name>US</short_name>
      <type>country</type>
      <type>political</type>
    </address_component>
    <geometry>
      <location>
        <lat>37.7786871</lat>
        <lng>-122.4212424</lng>
      </location>
      <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
      <viewport>
        <southwest>
          <lat>37.7694409</lat>
          <lng>-122.4298490</lng>
        </southwest>
        <northeast>
          <lat>37.7892260</lat>
          <lng>-122.4034491</lng>
        </northeast>
      </viewport>
      <bounds>
        <southwest>
          <lat>37.7694409</lat>
          <lng>-122.4298490</lng>
        </southwest>
        <northeast>
          <lat>37.7892260</lat>
          <lng>-122.4034491</lng>
        </northeast>
      </bounds>
    </geometry>
    <place_id>ChIJs88qnZmAhYARk8u-7t1Sc2g</place_id>
  </result>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

Comment: I don't see State/City in your xml, do you mean address?

Comment: State would be 'administrative_area_level_1' and city would be 'locality'

Comment: so I'm looking for 'San Francisco' and 'California'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this to get the state and locality from the `Xml`

```
var statesOrCity = doc.Descendants("address_component")
        .Where(e=>e.Elements("type").Any(x=>x.Value == "administrative_area_level_1" || x.Value == "locality"))
        .Select(c=> new {
            longname =c.Element("long_name").Value,
            shortname =c.Element("short_name").Value,
            State =  c.Element("type").Value== "locality"?  "State" : "City"
        });
```

Working [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/puA6FB)